# Managing different programs' volumes

Tags: windows-xp, audio

Is there any way to individually control each program's sound volume in Windows XP? It'd be better if it was built-in instead of an app, but whatever works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows XP doesn't have this feature built-in (Vista does, however).
You can use apps like

- [IndieVolume](http://www.indievolume.com/)

> IndieVolume allows every application
>   have separate volume level,
>   independent from other applications
>   volume level. For example, you are
>   listening to the music, and suddenly
>   some application LOUDLY shouts or
>   dings. With IndieVolume you just
>   configure shouting application to
>   sound at different (lower) volume
>   compared to the volume at which player
>   application is playing music.

Answer (score 0):

The only program I've seen that is capable of doing this on XP is [IndieVolume](http://www.indievolume.com/), and unfortunately it's not free.